# Need help to improve performance of a union with IN clause

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, union

I have a large query which I am trying to improve the performance of but not sure what to do with it.

Below is a simplified version but where the structure remains the same.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT A.Col1, SUM(B.Col2), SUM(C.Col3)
    FROM TableA A
       LEFT JOIN TableB B
           on A.Seq = B.Seq AND
              B.Nums in (1,2,3)
       LEFT JOIN TableC C
           on A.Seq = C.Seq AND
              C.Nums in (1,2,3)
     Where A.Location = 123456
     GROUP BY A.Col1
)

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT A.Col1, SUM(B.Col2), SUM(C.Col3)
    FROM TableA A
       LEFT JOIN TableB B
           on A.Seq = B.Seq AND
              B.Nums in (4,5,6)
       LEFT JOIN TableC C
           on A.Seq = C.Seq AND
              C.Nums in (4,5,6)
     Where A.Location = 123456
     GROUP BY A.Col1
)
```

Now the only difference between each union is the IN Clause of the joins. They contain different numbers. The LEFT joins are there on purpose.

At the moment I have two unions but i have a change request to increase this to 4 unions because we have some new numbers to retrieve which will be used in the IN clause.

This query is executed about 300 times where the Location number in the Where changes each time. Total execution time for 300 runs takes about 15 minutes. This will only increase with more unions.

Previously each individual SELECT was being performed in the code and then the individual DataTables were being merged. I created the union which improves the performance a little but not as much as i had hoped.

Any ideas?

Comment: how are your indexes set?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to improve query performance is the executionplan. That way you can see where the bottleneck is.

You haven't said anything about indexes, so if you haven't already, create them:

Indexes can be advanced but often simple ones will do:

```
CREATE INDEX idxTableASeq on TableA(Seq)
CREATE INDEX idxTableBSeq on TableB(Seq)
CREATE INDEX idxTableCSeq on TableC(Seq)
CREATE INDEX idxTableALocation on TableA(Location)
CREATE INDEX idxTableBNums on TableB(Nums)
CREATE INDEX idxTableCNums on TableC(Nums)
```

You will have to measure performance though.
While an index may improve selects, it can have a negative effect on inserts and updates.

Comment: Unfortunately i have no access to check the execution plan or create indexes. The query is run through a plugin program which the company provides.

Comment: Then I advise you to get in contact with the DBA or this will stay a guessing game.

Comment: Unfortunately i know from experience that the response from the DBAs will be NO Indexing Changes.

Answer (score 0):

You have a strange query, because you have multiple rows for the same value from "A", with no way to distinguish among them.  However, you can do what you want with a `case` in the `group by` and some logic in the `join`:

```
SELECT A.Col1, SUM(B.Col2), SUM(C.Col3)
FROM TableA A LEFT JOIN
     TableB B
     on A.Seq = B.Seq AND
        B.Nums in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) LEFT JOIN
     TableC C
     on A.Seq = C.Seq AND
        (coalesce(B.Nums, 1) IN (1, 2, 3) and C.Nums IN (1, 2, 3) or
         coalesce(B.Nums, 4) IN (4, 5, 6) and C.Nums IN (4, 5, 6)
        )
 Where A.Location = 123456 
 GROUP BY A.Col1,
          (CASE WHEN coalesce(B.Nums, C.Nums) in (1, 2, 3) then 1
                WHEN coalesce(B.Nums, C.Nums) in (4, 5, 6) then 2
           END);
```

Note: I think you should put the `case` expression in the `select` as well as the `group by`, so you can distinguish among the rows.

If I had to guess, the `c.num` is probably intended to be the same thing as `b.num`.  If so, you can simplify the second `on` clause to:

```
     on A.Seq = C.Seq AND
        (B.Nums = C.Nums OR C.Nums IN (1, 2, 3 4, 5, 6) )
```

Then, instead of executing the query multiple times, just put all the locations in the query and run it once:

```
SELECT A.location, A.Col1, SUM(B.Col2), SUM(C.Col3)
FROM TableA A LEFT JOIN
     TableB B
     on A.Seq = B.Seq AND
        B.Nums in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) LEFT JOIN
     TableC C
     on A.Seq = C.Seq AND
        (coalesce(B.Nums, 1) IN (1, 2, 3) and C.Nums IN (1, 2, 3) or
         coalesce(B.Nums, 4) IN (4, 5, 6) and C.Nums IN (4, 5, 6)
        )
 Where A.Location in (<list goes here>)
 GROUP BY A.location, A.Col1,
          (CASE WHEN coalesce(B.Nums, C.Nums) in (1, 2, 3) then 1
                WHEN coalesce(B.Nums, C.Nums) in (4, 5, 6) then 2
           END);
```

Comment: Without fully understanding the magic happening here, is the main point of this to avoid the `UNION ALL` or to improve performance? My understanding is that UNION in itself isn't very expensive, and your query seems to introduce some new complexity. In short, are you sure that this will be faster than the original version?

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg . . . (1) Running the query 300 times just to change a location is ludicrous. (2) Maintaining long complex queries with multiple similar subqueries is a nightmare.  (3) `union` is a performance problem, but the op is using `union all`.  In any case, there is no need to run the same subqueries multiple times.  (4) Before optimizing the query, I think it should be written for maintainability, readability, and be sure the produce the output that someone wants.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks ill try some of this but i cannot use an IN for the locations. Doing this creates too much data in a single query and the end client has a hardcoded restriction on the result set of each query being 100k records or less.

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg Yes i know running the query 300 times is madness but due to the client has a hardcoded restriction of 100k results per query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff all very fair points, thanks for explaining. For my non-expert eyes, your query is much harder to understand than the original though :) I'm still curious about performance impact, as that was OP's main concern (I mean, are there any straighforward ways to optimize this query which significantly cuts down execution time?). And I don't understand, how is `(coalesce(B.Nums, 1) IN (1, 2, 3) and C.Nums IN (1, 2, 3) or coalesce(B.Nums, 4) IN (4, 5, 6) and C.Nums IN (4, 5, 6))` ever different from just `C.Nums IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`? Sorry if being stupid.

Comment: You ask a lot of questions.  For the last one, the issue is that `left join`s can produce `NULL`s.  For the rest, I guess some people find that queries that fit on one page are easier to follow than those that go on and on -- and might have inadvertent errors in them.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to speed the query up would be to avoid the `in` clauses altogether. It seems to me that the possible values of B.Nums and C.Nums are inherently related in some sort of groups (hence you use one query for each set of "Nums"). If this is true, you could simply add a "NumsGroup" column to B and C that you prepopulate and then keep updated. E.g:

```
update B set NumsGroup = 1 where Nums in (1,2,3)
```

Then in your queries you can do e.g:

```
LEFT JOIN TableB B
  on A.Seq = B.Seq AND
  B.NumsGroup = 1
```

Depending on how many numbers are actually in your `in` clauses this should potentially speed things up quite a bit. Obviously it's a hassle to have to keep the NumsGroup column up to date on inserts and so. It would have been nicer to maintain the NumsGroup relationship in a separate table but then you'd have to use subselects and would probably lose more performance than you gain.